# Netbeans 7.3 firstcup example getting 404 on dukesAge service

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans

Even though I can hit the dukesAge service directly in different browsers with the exact same URI and get a valid answer, this code (copied exactly from the tutorial) is triggering a 404 exception in the get method:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/dukes-age/webapi/dukesAge");
String response = target.request().get(String.class);
```

I've looked at similar questions and answers here but they are using earlier versions of Netbeans and don't seem to apply. Any ideas here?

The example can be downloaded here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/firstcup/doc/intro002.htm

(Using Netbeans 7.3.1 and Glassfish 4.0 locally on Windows 7.)

Update: The code above triggers a handled exception so the only way you know about the error is that Duke's age appears as 0 instead of 18. You have to debug to see the actual 404 exception being thrown by the .get method. I also installed curl and when I try:

```
curl -G -v http://localhost:8080/dukes-age/webapi/dukesAge
```

it also shows the 404 error - but that url works fine in a browser. So I'm assuming it's something with my GlassFish setup but darned if I can find it.

Comment: I can't find this project between GF4 example projects. Where have you taken from?

Comment: Here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/firstcup/doc/intro002.htm

Comment: Ensure that you have installed all the updates from GF's update tool. And let us know: the code above comes from the dukesage_web project. Have you modified something in the project? Is the original project working or not?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled everything, just to be sure I had the right versions (full, not web) - same result even when I try the original project with no edits at all.

Comment: This is weird, I installed the projects yesterday, opened them with Netbeans and run them, everything worked immediately.

Comment: And duke's age wasn't zero? In mine, it "works" but his age remains zero because the webservice fails.

Comment: "works"?? And the 404 html error code? Please edit your question and make it understandable, otherwise it will be closed

Comment: I mean "works" in that the page comes up, you can fill in your birth date, etc. but it computes Duke's age as zero. When I debugged to why that was happening, I saw the 404 failure in the exception that was generated by the target.request call in the code above. It's just that the code traps the exception and keeps going so you don't notice if you don't pay attention to the actual value that is being displayed. Regardless, if I call the service directly from the browser, it returns the correct value of 18. It's only when the code calls the service that the 404 error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem in a more recent version (8.0), and the following solution fixed this for me:

[Status 404 on DukesAge project](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=214142#c2)

Specifically,

1. Open the Project Properties for dukes-age project.
2. In the **Run** section, ensure the **Relative URL** is set appropriately.  (i.e. "/webapi/dukesAge")

Comment: The link you provided referred to a [project](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=120814) that worked in Windows 10. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Found it! GlassFish http-listener-1 was listening to IP address 0.0.0.0 by default, which apparently works for hitting REST services in the browser. But changing that to localhost now let's it work for other clients like curl and other java clients that call the service.

Comment: Good that this solved your problem, but the IP address (not port, address) 0.0.0.0 works fine for me. It's still unclear why it didn't work for you

Comment: I downloaded the Java EE 8 on for Windows 10, running JDK 14.0.2. Once, I deployed the dukes-age, I received the page not found 404 error, even though, I had added the relative path /web API/dukesAge to the "Project->properties->Run". However, if I manually type the URL http://localhost:8080/dukes-age/webapi/dukesAge/ in the browser then it works fine and the application displays the duke's age properly.